# jsdoc module documentation with classes in seperate files

Tags: jsdoc

I'm trying to setup jsdoc in my codeing. The files are like the image bellow. The module is actaually the folder `skeleton`. What do I need to add to the two `class.js` files to get them included in my module generated with jsdoc?

[image]

Right now it is generated like this. It doesn't contain the information of the classes.
[image]

If I move my comment block from to my class files I get the image bellow, and if I place it in both files all info is duplicated.
[image]

The comment block I have is this

```
/**
 * Module defining the database structure. This module contains all table models as well as any validations or functions related to those models.
 * @module Skeleton
 * @author E. Koster
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @since 2.0.0
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it, it's @memberOf module:MODULE_NAME what I was looking for.